# call a function/sub on button click vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a button when clicked, a document will open...

```
Private Sub btnPrintDTR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintDTR.Click
    'function/sub to call
End Sub
```

in the "function to call", i want this `Sub DefineTables(ByVal document As Document)`
to be called.

i was able to call `Function SearchRecord() As DataTable` on button click using this code

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = SearchRecord()
```

i wanted a similar call but i could not figure out how to.
anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: Calling methods is one of the most elementary things you can do in programming. Any beginner tutorial would show you how. No one should be asking questions on this site without having made at least the effort to work through a beginner tutorial first. SO is for the stuff that you can't work out for yourself. This does not qualify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested to learn that you are system developer. One of the first things my husband would do when interviewing was to ask about items on the applicants resume.

I have no idea what type of Document your code refers to.

```
Private Sub btnPrintDTR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintDTR.Click
    Dim doc As New Document
    DefineTables(doc)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for taking time. well, am only making systems out of the code snippets i get over the net and do some tweaking. i know a bit bout functions but am confused about this one. what i did so far was `Private Sub btnPrintDTR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintDTR.Click
    document = DefineTables()
End Sub`

Comment: inside this function `Private Sub DefineTables(ByVal document As Document)` are codes to show datagridview to pdf. though i was able to achieve it using other methods, i still wanna know how to call it if am going to use this method.

Comment: Calling a Sub is demonstrated in my answer. I can't think what else you could possibly want to know about calling a Sub.

Answer (score 0):

oh now i get it...
by observing lots of functions...

`Private Sub btnPrintDTR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintDTR.Click
    DefineTables(document)
End Sub`